# How to put value in variable in Jenkinsfile with sshcommand

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to create a Pipeline in Jenkins which get the value of a command executed with sshCommand.
I've got a file like this on a remote server :

```
VALUE 11
```

Here is my Pipeline :

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Get Init') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId:'xxxxxxx', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
                script {
                    def remote = [:]
                    remote.name = 'xxxxxx'
                    remote.host = 'xxxxxx'
                    remote.user = USERNAME
                    remote.port = 22
                    remote.password = PASSWORD
                    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "init=\$(cat /var/log/myFile |  grep VALUE | awk '{print \$2}')"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Test") {
        steps {
            script {
                    test = sh(script "echo $init")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

}

I want to get the "11" in a variable to compare it later in my Jenkinsfile. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in below way :
Example:
 `def Result = sshCommand remote: remote, command: "<Your command>"`

```
# Declare variable init
def init
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Get Init') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId:'xxxxxxx', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
                script {
                    def remote = [:]
                    remote.name = 'xxxxxx'
                    remote.host = 'xxxxxx'
                    remote.user = USERNAME
                    remote.port = 22
                    remote.password = PASSWORD
                    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                    # Execute your command and take return value in the init variable
                    init= sshCommand remote: remote, command: "cat /var/log/myFile |  grep VALUE | awk '{print \$2}')"
                    echo "Initial Value: " + init
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Test") {
        steps {
            script {
                    test = sh(script "echo ${init}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```